# Arquivo .bat para gerar backup e restore em PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, backup

Estou criando arquivos .bat para realizar o backup e restauração de uma base de dados em PostgreSQL utilizo windows 10 e pg 9.4

Realizo o seguinte comando para realizar o backup

```
set PGUSER=postgres
set PGPASSWORD=postgres123

"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\"pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "D:\bkp.sql" "dbsibcom"
```

ele funciona perfeitamente.

E para realizar o restore tenho o seguinte comando

```
set PGUSER=postgres

set PGPASSWORD=postgres123
"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\pg_restore.exe -i -h localhost -p 5432 -c -d "testrestore" -v " D:\bkp.sql"
```

Crio o arquivo bat e tento restaurar, ele apenas abre e fecha a tela do dos rapidamente e não funciona.

Existe algo errado ou outro método de fazer o restore ?

tenho que dar alguma permissão para o pg ter acesso ao meu arquivo de backup ou algo do gênero?

Edição

---

Também tentei esses comandos para tentar realizar o restore e não funciona

```
set PGUSER=postgres
set PGPASSWORD=postgres123 

C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "testrestore"   --verbose "D:\bkp.sql"
```

Comment: está printando algum erro ? porque tem uma barra invertida ai \ /, tente todas no  mesmo  sentido, o caminho  está certo ?

Comment: tente esse caminho  com as aspas "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\pg_restore.exe"

Comment: Olá, não printa nenhum erro, apenas pisca a tela do dos e finaliza sem realizar nada

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considerando:

- O nome do banco de dados como: `minha_database`
- O arquivo de backup como: `C:\bkp\backup_database.dump`
- Instalação do PostgreSQL 9.1 em `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL`

> Pra fazer o backup:

```
C:\Progra~2\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\pg_dump -h servidor -p 5432 -U postgres --inserts -c -f C:\bkp\backup_database.dump minha_database
```

> Pra fazer o restore:

```
C:\Progra~2\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\psql -U postgres -d minha_database -f C:\bkp\backup_database.dump
```

- Você pode manter o comando `set PGPASSWORD=postgres123` pra não pedir a senha e automatizar a execução.
- Você pode colocar um comandou `pause` no final do `.bat` para ver qual erro ocorre.
- No seu ambiente, o caminho da pasta bin\ será: `C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\`. Utilize esse caminho para colocar os comandos.
- O arquivo de dump será gerado em formato sql, e em texto puro, sem nenhuma proteção / criptografia.

Comment: porque é utilizado o psql e não o pg_restore? o pg_restore não é utilizado para esses casos?. acabei de tentar implementar o backup, e não deu certo, ocorre o mesmo erro apenas pisca a tela e não funciona. Olhe como estou criando o arquivo .bar 
`set PGPASSWORD=postgres123


C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres --inserts -c -f D:\bkp2.dump basedados`

Comment: E com o restore ocorreu o mesmo erro. Se eu coloco essa caminho no endereço do explorer C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql ele me abre o .exe do pg normalmente mas quando eu crio o arquivo com a seguinte informação
`set PGPASSWORD=postgres123


C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql -U postgres -d testrestore -f D:\bkp.dump`
Ocorre o mesmo erro

Comment: Você poderia me falar qual o comando para realizar o pause?

Comment: kkkkk, Era isso mesmo, estava ocorrendo um erro por conta do  C:\Program Files, ele falava que "C:\Program" não era reconhecido. muito obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: Quando se faz um backup de um banco, seu arquivo .dump vem com caracteres especiais? quando eu executo o restore aparece varios caracteres especiais e comandos invalidos. invalidando assim meu restore

Comment: Mas a minha dúvida é, se eu faço backup de um banco em .sql e abro ele em um editor de texto eu consigo ver todos os dados? ou os dados aparecem com caracteres especiais como uma forma de proteção? por que aqui no meu caso, meu banco está em ENCODING = 'UTF8', porém caso eu abra meu arquivo backup gerado no notepad++ por exemplo ele vem com alguns caracteres nesse formato ``Zë¿nE=1~:Ò ÉEÝo‰³a25ÙPL…&` e varios nulls

Comment: Certo Obrigado pela ajuda, deve ter algo errado com o meu Encoding quano realizo o backup então

Comment: blz, alterei a resposta acrescentando as informações dos comentários. e vou apagar os comentários desnecessários. vlw

Answer (score 0):

Script de backup

```
Windows 

@Echo Off
 @For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @(
 Set DayW=%%A
 Set Day=%%B
 Set Month=%%C
 Set Year=%%D
 Set All=%%A_%%B_%%C_%%D
 )
 @For /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:,. " %%A in ('echo %time%') do @(
 Set Hour=%%A
 Set Min=%%B
 Set Sec=%%C
 Set Allm=%%A.%%B.%%C
 )
 @For /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%A in ('time /t ') do @(
 Set AMPM=%%A
 )
set datestr=%All%%Allm%%AMPM%
echo datestr is %datestr%

set BACKUP_FILE=E:\BACKUP\WMSBACKUP_%datestr%.backup
echo backup file name is %BACKUP_FILE%
SET PGPASSWORD=suasenha
echo on
cd "\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\"
pg_dump.exe -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 wms > %BACKUP_FILE% 

pause
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@echo off

rem Coloca o nome do banco aqui

set banco=

REM Senha da base de dados

SET PGPASSWORD=

rem Caminho da pasta do backup

set pastabk=D:\backup_sistema

rem Caminho do pg_dump

set pg_dump=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin

rem Unidade do HD EXTERNO

set pendrive=G:\

rem Nome do Servidor

set servidor=

if not exist %pastabk% (mkdir %pastabk%)

color 1f

Title BACKUP SISTEMA

echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo -----------------------Backup de banco de dados-----------------------


echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo.

set dia=%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%

set dia=%dia: =%

echo Banco de Dados.: %banco%

echo.

cd\

CD %pg_dump%

pg_dump.exe -h %servidor% -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f 
"%pastabk%\%banco%%dia%.backup" %banco%

echo.

echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo.


if exist %pastabk%\%banco%%dia%.backup (

    echo Backup Concluido... 

    echo Criado no arquivo: "%pastabk%\%banco%%dia%.backup".

    echo.

    if exist %pendrive% (

        echo Copiando arquivo para dispositivo removivel.

        if not exist %pendrive%\BancosBk\ (md %pendrive%BancosBk\)
 
        copy "%pastabk%\%banco%%dia%.backup" 
"%pendrive%\BancosBk\%banco%%dia%.backup"

        echo.

        echo Backup copiado para dispositivo removivel.

        echo Copiando em %pendrive%\BancosBk\%banco%%dia%.backup

    ) else (echo Dispositivo removivel nao encontrado.)

) else (echo Não foi possivel concluir o backup.)


echo.

pause
```

Comment: OBS: COPIAR OS ARQUIVOS DA PASTA BIN PARA A SYSTEM32

Comment: Você pode editar a resposta para incluir o texto no comentário.