# Dúvida com campos de Imagem no Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Usei o sql a baixo para visualizar o tamanho de todas as tabelas do banco, ele me retornar um total de 98 MB, mais como o banco tem imagens que são gravadas como Binário e as mesmas não estão em uma tabela, gostaria de fazer um backup do banco sem estas imagens,existe alguma forma de remover estas imagens?

agradeço a ajuda

```html
SELECT
  table_name,
  pg_size_pretty(table_size)   || ' (' || CASE WHEN total_size = 0 THEN 0.00 ELSE round(table_size * 100 / total_size) END   || ' %)' AS table_size,
  pg_size_pretty(indexes_size) || ' (' || CASE WHEN total_size = 0 THEN 0.00 ELSE round(indexes_size * 100 / total_size) END || ' %)' AS indexes_size,
  pg_size_pretty(total_size)                                                                                                          AS total_size
FROM (
 (SELECT
  table_name,
  pg_table_size(table_name)          AS table_size,
  pg_indexes_size(table_name)        AS indexes_size,
  pg_total_relation_size(table_name) AS total_size
 FROM (
  SELECT ('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') AS table_name
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE NOT table_schema IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
 ) AS all_tables
 ORDER BY total_size DESC)

 UNION ALL

 (SELECT
  'TOTAL',
  sum(pg_table_size(table_name))          AS table_size,
  sum(pg_indexes_size(table_name))        AS indexes_size,
  sum(pg_total_relation_size(table_name)) AS total_size
 FROM (
  SELECT ('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') AS table_name
  FROM information_schema.tables
```

```html
--Encontrando as tabelas que referenciam Large Objects

SELECT nspname AS esquema, relname AS tabela, attname AS coluna
FROM
             pg_type t
        JOIN pg_attribute a  ON a.atttypid = t.oid
        JOIN pg_class c      ON a.attrelid = c.oid
        JOIN pg_namespace n  ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
WHERE
    typname IN  ('oid','lo') AND
    attname NOT IN ('oid', 'tableoid') AND
    nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'information_schema');
```

Tabelas com Imagens:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Solução Proposta :

1 - Acessei o CMD

2 - C:\PostgreSQL96\bin\pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 --no-tablespaces -U postgres --inserts -c -f C:\bkp\backup_ezitus.dump ezitus-prod

3 - Pediu a senha

4 - Gerou o backup do banco

Comment: banco tem imagens como binário, e não estão em uma tabela ? como assim ? estão onde ?

Comment: O banco possui imagens gravadas, mais estas imagens não tem uma tabela, tanto que ao fazer uma consulta usando o sql a cima, tenho um banco com 98 MB, quando gerar um backup fica com 4 GB, porque tem imagens em uma tabela tablespace, eu quero um backup apenas com as tabelas sem imagem.

Comment: e como está realizando o backup ?

Comment: Estou usando a opção visual do Postgres

Comment: nessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250074/69359 utilizo o pg_dump para realizar o backup. Nele há um parâmetro `--no-tablespaces` que pode ser útil à você. Documentação completa: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Gerou o backup do banco, vou testar a restauração, agradeço a ajuda

Comment: O arquivo final ficou com 10GB, então não deu certo