# pg_dump executado via prompt de comando do windows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Executei um `dump` com o seguinte script:

```
C:\Arquivos de Programas\postgresql\10\bin>pg_dump.exe -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 5432 -U postgres -W postgres
Senha:...

-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 10.1
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.1

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- Name: postgres; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: postgres
--

COMMENT ON DATABASE postgres IS 'default administrative connection database';


--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner:
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner:
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


--
-- Name: adminpack; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner:
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS adminpack WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION adminpack; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner:
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION adminpack IS 'administrative functions for PostgreSQL';


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Minha dúvida é, se o backup foi executado, onde está o arquivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não informou o parametro `-f` especificando o arquivo, o dump só foi exibido no prompt, e não salvo.

O comando correto seria:

```
C:\Arquivos de Programas\postgresql\10\bin>pg_dump.exe -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 5432 -U postgres -f C:\backup\meudump.dump database_nome
```

Há uma resposta minha aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250074/69359 mostrando como realizar o dump.

Documentação do `pg_dump`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Obrigado, consegui! Salvei acrescentando ".sql" ao final do "-f". Esse arquivo gerado pelodump, eu posso carrega-lo no  MySQL para modelar as tabelas pelo workbench?

Comment: é um arquivo de dump do postgresql, logo, os comandos presentes nele são específicos de uma base postgres. Certamente não vai funcionar. Não se esqueça de marcar como resposta

Comment: marcar como resposta?

Comment: Há um V logo abaixo da votação da resposta, que você marca qual solucionou seu problema. Faça o tour para ver como funciona a comunidade: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour